# How to conditionally populate a form's placeholder?

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuex

I have a form I want to allow user submission to with a field called "Job Position."  I also have an array of `Jobs` with a `Job Position` attribute I'm getting from my vue store.  When someone clicks on a job from the list of jobs (series of buttons generated with v-for), I want the form to fill the `Job Position` field with that particular job's job position (while still allowing people to create new jobs on submit as desired).

I have successfully console.logged both my `listOfJobs` array and the activeJobIndex for the job on:click.  `{{listOfJobs[activeJobIndex].jobPosition}}` is usable within my vue file.

```
<div>* Position Title: {{ positionform }}</div>
    <b-form-input v-model="positionform" type="text" size="sm"></b-form-input>
</div>
```

```
data() {
    return {
      positionform: 'Position',
    }
}
```

On first visiting the page, I want the Job Position field to read "Position" which it currently does.  I want the user to be able to submit their own Job Position for a new job, which my form allows.  And I would like the user to click on a currently listed job and have the Job Position field populated with the job position for that job, which I have not yet been able to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `v-on:click` to a method who will set `positionform` to `listOfJobs[activeJobIndex].jobPosition`

You didn't give much code but it would look something like that :

```
<component v-on:click="handleSelect"></component>
```

```
methods: {
    handleSelect (jobPosition) {
      // jobPosition is listOfJobs[activeJobIndex].jobPosition
      this.positionform = jobPosition; 
    }
}
```